# Given $A_n : X\rightarrow Y$ linear and continuous, for each $x\in X$ $A_n(x) \rightharpoonup A(x)$ in $Y$, is $A$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory

> Given $A_n : X\rightarrow B$, a linear and continuous operator between two Banach spaces, for each $x\in X$ $A_n(x)
>  \rightharpoonup A(x)$ in $Y$, is $A$ linear and continuous?

My attempt:

$A$ is linear, given $A(x + y)$, then there exists a sequence $A_n(x+y)$ which converges weakly to $A(x+y)$ and $A_n(x+y) = A_n x + A_n y $ which converges weakly to $Ax + Ay$.

To show $A$is bounded, since $A_n (x) \rightharpoonup A(x)$, we have
$$\|A(x)\|_Y \leq \liminf \|A_n (x) \|_Y$$
and that $\|A_n (x) \|_Y$ is bounded.

Using uniform boundedness principle, we get that $\|A_n\|_{op}$ is bounded.

Thus,
$$\|A(x)\|_Y \leq \liminf \|A_n (x) \|_Y \leq \liminf \|A_n\|_{op} \|x\|_X .$$

**Question:** Is this correct? I am not so sure since the Banach-Saks-Steinhaus theorem has the same result with the assumption that $A_n(x)$ is strongly convergent (Cauchy) in $Y$ (instead of weak convergence like in this problem).

Comment: You proof is correct. You could have stated more clearly that $(\Vert A_n(x) \Vert_Y)_n$ is bounded by the uniform boundedness principle (or because weakly convergent sequences are bounded).

Comment: Thank you very much! I did say that the boundedness together with the liminf inequality come from the weak convergence : )

Comment: Yes, I know. You just did not explicitely say something like "because weakly convergent sequences are bounded" :) Maybe I am overly pedantic.